# RNN time series predictions with multiple time series dimension with Keras, Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to run a RNN/LSTM network on some time series sets. It should be mentioned that the time series are being classified. I have ~600 different time series, and each of these has 930 timesteps with features in them. I have structured my data into a numpy 3D array that is structured like:

```
X = [666 observations/series, 930 timesteps in each observation, 15 features]
Y = [666 observations/series, 930 timesteps in each observation, 2 features]
```

For training and validation data I split the data 70/30. So Train_X = [466, 930, 15] and Train_Y = [200, 930, 2].

My network is getting an error that is saying that it expected the input to be 2 dimensions and that it got an array with shape (466, 930, 2). My code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Bidirectional

Train_X = new_ped_data[0:466]
Test_X = new_ped_data[466:]

Train_Y = new_ped_valid_data[0:466]
Test_Y = new_ped_valid_data[466:]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True),
                        input_shape=Train_X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(10)))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.compile(loss='mae', 
              optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(Train_X, Train_Y, epochs = 30, batch_size = 32, 
      validation_data =(Test_X, Test_Y))
```

I am just trying to get the model running. Once I do, then I'll tweak the architecture and fit parameters. I should mention that one of the classification outputs might not be necessary. Any suggestions as to how I set up the architecture so that if a time series is fed in I will get the classification values of the network for each timestep?

```
Error was: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to
have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (466, 930, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output has also sequential nature. `LSTM` by default has a flag `return_sequences=False`. This makes your sequence to be squashed to a vector after the second `LSTM` layer. In order to change that try:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True),
                    input_shape=Train_X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.compile(loss='mae', 
          optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Comment: Hmm with that modification I now have: `Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (None, 930, 5) but got array with shape (466, 930, 2)`

Comment: Change this line:  `model.add(Dense(2))`

Comment: I would add `BatchNormalization` and then try `batch_size` from set `[16, 32, 64, 128]`. It's high data dependent issue.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I try to use your code, but my data have shape `x_train=(117, 73742, 118), y_train=(117, 73744, 118), x_val=(13, 73742, 118), y_val=(13, 73744, 118)`, and I have error `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_14 to have shape (73742, 118) but got array with shape (73744, 118)`. How can I fit my model, if `x` and `y` have different shape?

Comment: @PetrPetrov Your data shapes are different... You need to have the same dimensions. How is it possible that you have a different number of inputs vs outputs?