# RNN: predictions with different input and output

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to run a RNN/LSTM network on vectorized text. 
I have structured my data into a numpy 3D array that is structured like:

```
X_train = (117 quantity of objects, 73742 length of text (quantity of chars), 118 (size of dictionary))
y_train = (117 quantity of objects, 73744 length of text (quantity of chars), 118 (size of dictionary))
```

Difference connected with markup of y text (I try to solve task of Name Entity Recognition)

I build model with

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True),
                input_shape=y_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(118))
model.compile(loss='mae', 
      optimizer='rmsprop')

model.summary()
```

But after running

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 30, batch_size = 32, 
  validation_data =(x_val, y_val))
```

it returns me an error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected bidirectional_30_input to have shape (73744, 118) but got array with shape (73742, 118)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: The answer is right there in the error message. The `y_train` data has text length 73744 (from top of post), but the error says your `y_val` data is length 73742 (~= 73744).

Comment: two of your samples in `X_train` are missing their target values (`y_train`), either drop those two samples from your dataset or figure out what are your `y_train` target values.

Comment: @user69513 no, `y_val = (13, 73744, 118)`

Comment: @Flika205 yes, y it's markup text, so I have more chars in y text, so array has another shape

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if it's specifically the size of `y_val` causing the issue but you clearly have a sizing problem of some sort. You have `x_train` at 73742, `y_train` doesn't match (it's 73744), then you have `x_val` and `y_val` but didn't show us the code for that, and you end up with an error complaining that it expected *something* to be 73744 but instead it was 73742. If it's not specifically `y_val` that's the problem, then go read the docs because it's something to do with a size mismatch. Are you certain you're allowed to have objects of different size here?

Comment: @user69513 I find common question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253348/rnn-time-series-predictions-with-multiple-time-series-dimension-with-keras-tens` and there is different shape in y and x